# find a given word in between brackets in a string python regex

Tags: python, regex, string, cpu-word

I want to find out if a string contains the word "randomize". This word my exist in and outside of brackets in the string but I am only interested if the word exists IN SIDE of the brackets.

```
mystring = "You said {single order='randomize'} that P.E is...Why?"
```

I understand that i have to use regex for this but my attampts have failed thus far.

Essentially I want to say:

```
look for "randomize" and check if its in brackets.
```

Thanks

Comment: Can the brackets be nested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some negated classes:

```
>>> import re
>>> mystring = "You said {single order='randomize'} that P.E is...Why?"
>>> if mystring.find("randomize") != -1:
...     if re.search(r'{[^{}]*randomize[^{}]*}', mystring):
...         print("'randomize' present within braces")
...     else:
...         print("'randomize' present but not within braces")
... else:
...     print("'randomize' absent")

# => 'randomize' present within braces
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution since it short-circuits the expensive regex lookup if the string doesn't contain `randomize` at all. +1

Comment: @arshajii - I'm sure he didn't do the find() to 'short circuit' anything, rather to provide extra information since the regex is looking for an explicit construct. Besides, its possible "randomize" is in every string.

Comment: @sln The first sentence of the question: `I want to find out if a string contains the word "randomize"`...

Comment: Yep, see that now. But, the next sentence he don't care. Go figure.

Comment: Or, `{[^{}]*(randomize)[^{}]*}|randomize` ? { group 1 ? inside : outside } : not there;

Answer (score 0):

The naive simple method:

```
>>> import re
>>> mystring = "You said {single order='randomize'} that P.E is...Why?"
>>> print re.search('{.*randomize.*}', mystring).group(0)
```

Once we have this, we can improve it bit by bit. For instance, this is called a greedy regex, which means:

```
>>> print re.search('{.*randomize*}', "{FOO {randomize} BAR}").group(0)
{FOO {randomize} BAR}
```

You'll probably want it to be non-greedy, so you should use '.*?' instead:

```
>>> print re.search('{.*?randomize.*?}', mystring).group(0)
```

Also, it will not handle nested:

```
>>> print re.search('{.*?randomize.*?}', "{FOO} randomize {BAR}").group(0)
{FOO} randomize {BAR}
```

If you want to handle simple nested, you may want to match all characters except other brackets.

```
>>> print re.search('{[^}]*randomize[^{]*}', mystring).group(0)
```

Comment: very naive and very simple! This will match any string with an open bracket, a close bracket, and the word "randomize" between them, as my answer points out =/

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of thing that's very difficult for regex to do. You see if you do something like `re.escape(r"{.*?randomize.*?}")`, you can match something like `"Hello there, I'm going to {break} your randomize regex {foobar}"` and it will return `"{break} your randomize regex {foobar}"`. You can probably pull this off with lookahead and lookbehind assertions, but not without telling us if the brackets can be nested, since this will then fail on `"I'm going to break you {now with randomize {nested} brackets}"`

As per your update that the brackets will never be nested, this regex should match:

```
re.search("{[^}]*?randomize.*?}", mystring)
```

And you can access the group using `.group(0)`. Put it all together to do something like:

```
for mystring in group_of_strings_to_test:
    if re.search("{[^}]*?randomize.*?}", mystring).group(0):
        # it has "randomize" in a bracket
    else:
        # it doesn't.
```

Comment: Very interesting. The brackets will never be nested, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To assure you're not inside nested {}'s it could be

```
 {[^{}]*randomize[^{}]*}
```